# Email address changed while contact in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have scenario where contact added/injected to Journey Builder. Journey duration is one week and there is one email going every day.

Let say contact A injected to journey on Monday with email E1, on Wednesday contact A's Email changed to E2, Thursday onward which email will be used to send email until end of journey.

Salesforce ID is subscriber key.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4):

When Contact A is initially injected into the Journey and reaches a Send Email Activity, a Subscriber record is created (if one does not already exist).

If the email address changes while the contact is in the Journey (for example, the email address is updated as defined in the Channel Address Order), or even if the Contact exits the Journey then enters the Journey again at a later date, the previous email will still be used.

This behavior is not unique to Journey Builder either; if you have a Sendable Data Extension and complete a Guided Send Email, then repeat this again at a later date with updated email addresses in the in the Sendable DE, the emails will be sent to the previous Subscriber. The issue is that Salesforce assume all subscribers are using the built-in profile centre to update their email address. But this is often not the case.

The solution isn't great, but its really the only way around this. You will need to create a Scheduled Automation in Automation Studio that runs at a regular interval (e.g. daily) and performs the following tasks:

1. SQL Query Activity to identify updated email addresses
2. Export Target DE from Query Activity to Enhanced FTP Account using File Transfer Activity
3. Import the file exported in step 2 to the All Subscribers list using Import File Activity (refer to screenshot below).

[image: all subscribers]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to provide an update on this as the behavior appears to have recently changed.

If the email address changes while the contact is in the Journey (specifically, an email address in the Data Extension which is used by the Channel Address Order), the **new email address** will be used for subsequent Send Email Activities and the Subscriber record (in All Subscribers) **will be updated** with the new email address.

I haven't checked what the behavior is if you are using an email address in your Event Source DE (I suspect that this will still use the original email address), but providing you are updating the email addresses defined by the Channel Address Order, this definitely works!

Comment: I have checked and it still use old email address not new one. 
Salesforce id is Subscriber key

Comment: Can you check the Default Channel Address in your Journey Settings? Is it using the email from the Channel Address Order as the Primary Email? This should work (it does for me!)

Answer (score 0):

As Journey Builder keep two types of contacts.
1. Snapshot of contact when contact added to Journey builder called "Event Data".
2. Contact in data source data extension called "Contact Data".

So throughout the journey Event Data will be used but you can use AMPScript or Splits to compare the Event Data and Contact Data.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not credible enough to comment yet, therefore a separate answer.

I was recently told by Salesforce Solution Experts that there are two scenarios:
- Channel Address Order (Journey Builder)
- The Email in All Subscribers.

If you update the journey, and have set it to "Use channel address order" and not the email that was in the event source DE - the above should work.

However, @Eliot - have you seen it automatically updating the All Subs list if you send to a new channel address email?