# How to handle contacts email addresses that change midfligh in a Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have a journey which lasts 6 months, we have noticed some customers during that time update their email addresses. When this happens they continue to receive comms to their old email address. How can we resolve this?

Comment: That is not correct. Email from entry source will not reflect updates mid journey. To honor changes mid journey, you will need to set default email to contacts and not entry source

Comment: @Tyler if we set the email source as the Contact.. If the subscriber doesn’t exist will it create one?

Comment: It will not. You’d just have to automate an import with your audience to all subscribers before injecting them into the journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link explains how to handle such scenarios
[Email address changed while contact in Journey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145029/email-address-changed-while-contact-in-journey)